# Changing variable on button-click using JQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, geojson

I am attempting to build a web feature that allows the user to select a window of time to see local Earthquake information, using information found here. 
https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php

As you can see here, (https://codepen.io/JoshTheGray/pen/yPmJeR) I am having success parsing the information when I statically assign the url variable for whatever timeframe I want, however I am running into trouble trying to make that url variable change, based on a user button click.

**My HTML**

```
<div>Please select a window of time to see Earthquake information.</div>
<br>

<button id="1HourButton">Past Hour</button>
<button id="1DayButton">Past 24 Hours</button>
<br>
<br>


<div id="output1">Earthquakes Around the State<br><br></div>
<br>
```

**My JavaScript / JQuery**

```
;(function($){
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        // testing document load state
        console.log( "document loaded" );
    var output1 =document.getElementById('output1');
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Asigns url based on button choice from user.
    var url = '';

    $('#1HourButton').click(function () {
        url = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_hour.geojson';
        console.log(url);
    });
    $('#1DayButton').click(function () {
        url = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson';
        console.log(url);
    });

    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200){
            var myObj = JSON.parse(hr.response);

            for(i=0; i < myObj.features.length; i++) {
        if (myObj.features[i].properties.title.includes("Alaska")) {
                output1.innerHTML += myObj.features[i].properties.title + '<br>';
        }
            }
        }
    }

    hr.open("GET", url, true);
    hr.send();

    });
})(jQuery);
```

=========================

Currently I am seeing the correct URL information passed to the console upon button click, but the json information is no longer coming through.

What am I missing?

Comment: As it is now, `hr.open("GET", url, true);` is executed before any of the buttons is clicked (before the `url` variable is changed). You'll have to execute that statement after you change the value of the `url` variable.

Comment: So do I just need to move that outside the document.ready function?

Comment: No, you can extract all the code used to make an AJAX request into a function that accepts the URL as a parameter.

Comment: Another option is to move the `hr.open("GET", url, true); hr.send();` statements into the callback function of the click event listeners.

Comment: So that works, but now the information just stacks. Hmm I need to figure out how to replace the information displayed with each subsequent button-press. This helped immensely though, thank you Titus.

Comment: You could add a `output1.innerHTML = ""` statement before the loop so you clear that element.